# How can I associate my main domain to a RSS?

Tags: domains, rss, tumblr

This is an institutional site which uses Tumblr to keep the visitors updated. The Tumblr is linked via frames in the subdirectory /blog/ of the domain to track stats. My question is:

How can I allow my visitors to retrieve the Tumblr updates by simply inputing *www.domain.com* in their feed reader instead of domain.tumblr.com?

OR

How can I allow my visitors to retrieve the Tumblr updates by simply inputing *www.domain.com/blog* in their feed reader instead of domain.tumblr.com?

PS. For some reason the main domain is still associated with the old blogspot address.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the source code for your Tumblr site, you'll see a feed auto-discovery link in the head section that'll look like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="/rss">
```

Copy that line, and in your text editor, change it to:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://domain.tumblr.com/rss">
```

(Replace domain.tumblr.com with whatever your actual Tumblr address is)
Add that line to the template for the rest of your regular site, in the head section.